# Dynamic Loading of external javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I accomplish this? Every time I try to load an external javascript file from google maps, it crashes the webpage and it becomes blank.

I used the $JQuery.get(); function.

I am using JQuery to load the file into the head.

Comment: Could you post some code? How do you *load* your file?

Comment: do you have a code excerpt of how you're trying to do this?

Comment: Did you try jQuery's getscript? (http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getScript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google maps probably uses `document.write`. That explains the blank page. This is why `document.write` is evil.

Try downloading the google js file to disk and search for `document.write`. If it's there then your only option is to include it normally using the `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery doesn't do (rightly) cross-domain ajax requests without a callback. See the note at the bottom of the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options).

Comment: the OP didn't say anything about using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the Google Maps API has some restriction in it's usage, and you need to link to it when you load the page, even if you don't immediately make use of it. You will also need to have the target div on the page initially as well (and in it's proper location), even if it's hidden on load.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code that I use in our app:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>geocoder test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
        function jsonp(src){
            var s = document.createElement("script");
            s.charset = "UTF-8";
            s.src = encodeURI(src);
            s.id = 'jsonp';
            document.body.appendChild(s);
            return s;
        };

        function showMap(json){
            var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas'), 
                jsonp = document.getElementById('jsonp');
            if(json.Status.code !== 200){
                mapCanvas.innerHTML = 'Address not found';
                return false;
            }
            var ll = json.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates,
                latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(ll[1], ll[0]),
            myOptions = {
                zoom: 16,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            },
            map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, myOptions),
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map
            });
            jsonp.parentNode.removeChild(jsonp);
        }

        function getMap(address){
            jsonp([
                'http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?',
                'q=' + address,
                '&output=json',
                '&sensor=false',
                //'&key= ... place here your key if not on localhost ...',
                '&callback=showMap'
            ].join(''));
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" value="gran place, brussels"/><input type="button" onclick="getMap(this.previousSibling.value)" value="Get Map"/>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:450px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a function that does exactly this: [`$.getScript`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getScript#urlcallback). For example:

```
$.getScript('/script.js', function()
{
    alert('Script loaded!');
});
```